# Как правильно настроить ftp сервер на debian?

Tags: ftp, linux, debian, сервер

Задача - поднять FTP сервер.
Использую vsftpd.

При рестарте появляется следующая ошибка:

> root@test-lisa2:/var/log# /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
>
> Restarting FTP server: vsftpdNo /usr/sbin/vsftpd found running; none killed.

В файле конфигурации следующее:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YESн
ftpd_banner=Welcome!
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
ls_recurse_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Никаких дополнительных директорий (в соответствии с разными руководствами) не создавала пока, хочу сначала разобраться, чтобы все не испортить.

Вопрос, в чем я не права и как сделать сервер рабочим? Понятно, что нужно создать пользователей и необходимые для работы директории, но пусть перезапустится сначала нормально.

---

Проблема решилась включением лога программы в файл конфигурации

```
syslog_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd1.log
```

соответствующие файлы /var/log/vsftpd1.log и /var/log/vsftpd.log создать вручную.

Теперь вопрос стоит следующим образом - почему программа стала работать нормально? Как это связано? Мне очень важно понимать именно механизм для осознания своих действий.

Comment: Насчет лога - та же ситуация и с Апачем, если указать на несуществующую папку - сервер крашится... Имхо, считаю это никчемной недоработкой :)

Answer (score 1):

По поводу:

```
syslog_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd1.log
```

Скорее всего стандартные значения syslog_enable=YES xferlog_enable=YES, при этом xferlog_file либо задана не правильно либо задано место в которое демон не имеет прав на запись. Проверить это вы можете убрав первые две строки.

Comment: syslog_enable= здесь стандартное значение по документации - NO 

а вот влияние xferlog_file действительно похоже есть.

Comment: Да кстати попробуйте посмотреть что в лог пишется, возможно там есть полезная информация. И еще вопрос в документации второй лог тоже в NO?

Comment: нет. 
а в логах - ничего. правда забавно? В системном логе и в логе демонов тоже ничего. 

я вообще не знаю куда оно свои события заносит и заносит ли вообще. 
Возможно нужно нормальное подключение к чему-нибудь для начала. А потом уже остальные радости в логах. Похоже просто работу он не фиксирует.

Answer (score 0):

А он вообще запущен?

/etc/init.d/vsftpd start

Comment: Конечно. Не настолько ж я чайник. 
Это меня и напрягает - что он не отключается. 
Номер процесса не 4634 - где нужно закомментировать строку бэкграунд, а 9718. что это - пока не знаю, буду искать.

Умных панелей ispmanager там нет ) В этом вся соль - поставить все функции ispmgr сторонними приложениями вручную настроив конфиги.

Comment: Хорошо, а почему в конфиге chroot_list включен, но не установлен?
Пробовали менять по одной опции из дефолтного конфига на ваши и смотреть,
где он завалится?

Comment: Просто такое ощущение, что он стартует, но не демонизируется.

Comment: чисто из интереса заменила вообще на дефолтный конфиг - тоже самое. может где-нибудь ещё копать? Системные логи смотрела, лог демонов смотрела - ничего. То есть вообще ничего касательно ftp.

Он может конфликтовать с чем-либо?

Comment: Проблема решена, однако очень интересно узнать почему решилась именно так.